Predictive Maintenance of factory parts
I'm training a model to perform predictive maintenance of a particular part in a factory. I have performed data cleaning like removing the null, duplicate values, removing the highly correlated columns using a heatmap and using the IQR value to remove outliers. I have also performed univariate, bivariate and multivariate analysis of the data.
I used ARIMA to perform univariate training then moved forward to training an XGBoost model to perform multivariate training for more accurate results. However, my AutoARIMA is giving highly inaccurate results.
My columns/features are:

new_State                                             object
previous_State                                        object
positionName                                          object
asset_Name                                            object
year                                                   int32
month                                                  int32
day                                                    int32
hour                                                   int32
second                                                 int32
accelaration_band10To1000Hz_Vibration_absMax         float64
velocity_band10To1000Hz_X_rms                        float64
velocity_band10To1000Hz_Y_rms                        float64
velocity_band10To1000Hz_Z_rms                        float64
velocity_band10To1000Hz_Vibration_crestFactor        float64
velocity_band10To1000Hz_Vibration_rms                float64
velocity_band10To1000Hz_Vibration_absMax             float64
acceleration_band10To1000Hz_Vibration_crestFactor    float64
acceleration_band10To1000Hz_Vibration_rms            float64
acceleration_band0To6000Hz_X_rms                     float64
acceleration_band0To6000Hz_Y_rms                     float64
acceleration_band0To6000Hz_Z_rms                     float64
acceleration_band10To1000Hz_X_rms                    float64
acceleration_band10To1000Hz_Y_rms                    float64
acceleration_band10To1000Hz_Z_rms                    float64
temperature                                          float64
new_State_encoded    int32

The temperature graph:

code for AutoARIMA:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pmdarima import auto_arima
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# Assuming your train and test data are already defined
train = no_waste['temperature'].iloc[:int(0.8*len(no_waste))]
test = no_waste['temperature'].iloc[int(0.8*len(no_waste)):]

# Reduce the range of parameters to reduce computational burden
model = auto_arima(train, 
                   start_p=0, d=1, start_q=0, 
                   max_p=2, max_d=2, max_q=2,  # Further reduce the maximum values for p, d, q
                   start_P=0, D=1, start_Q=0, 
                   max_P=1, max_D=1, max_Q=1,  # Further reduce seasonal parameters
                   #m=24,  # Set m to 24 for daily seasonality with hourly data
                   seasonal=True, 
                   error_action='warn', 
                   trace=True, 
                   suppress_warnings=True, 
                   stepwise=True, 
                   n_jobs=1,  # Use stepwise search to reduce memory usage
                   random_state=20, 
                   n_fits=5)  # Further reduce the number of fits
# Print model summary
print(model.summary())

# Make predictions
start_index = len(train)
end_index = len(train) + len(test) - 1
predictions = model.predict(n_periods=len(test))

# Create a datetime index for the predictions
pred_dates = test.index

# Create Plotly figure
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=1)

# Add traces for train, test data, and predictions
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=train.index, y=train, mode='lines', name='Train', line=dict(color='blue')))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=test.index, y=test, mode='lines', name='Test', line=dict(color='orange')))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=pred_dates, y=predictions, mode='lines', name='Predictions', line=dict(color='red')))

# Update layout
fig.update_layout(
    title='Train-Test Split with Auto ARIMA Model Predictions',
    xaxis_title='Date',
    yaxis_title='Temperature',
    legend_title='Legend'
)

# Show plot
fig.show()

When I try to execute the above code it gives me a memoryError or if I remove the seasonality term it gives me a highly inaccurate graph.


Welcome to Cross Validated! What is your question, how to fix your code? How to use XGBoost to make better predictions?

I wanted to know how to fix my code so that the prediction plot is more accurate

Given that you know the periodicity, I would suggest that you aim to make a model to predict the 24-hour sliding average, and another to predict the daily variation. For the latter, the training set is, for each time point $t$ in the day, $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^n(t+24i)$

Could you give me a little more guidance on how I would go about doing so?

Make two datasets and consider them separately. Firstly, the 24-hour sliding average. If you plot that, it will show a slow increase, which perhaps levelled off in March. Secondly, the daily variation, calculated by the formula I shared above. Actually on a closer look there is also a weekly component - it looks as if they do not work weekends, except for one occasion in January,

Sure, thing I'll try it out and let you know. Thank you for the insight.
